# Irrational numbers impossible?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Okay, I am more than aware that my logic has fallen through somewhere so please show me where.

But surely irrational numbers can't exist.

Okay, so an irrational number is infinitely long and never repeats, yeah?

But surely those things can't go hand in hand. Either it can be infinitely long, or never repeat, one would stop the other.

So each time you add a new number you reduce the chances, and there's an infinite number of numbers so you have a 1/infinity chance of getting the right number and remainder/no remainder. But you also have an infinite number of possibilities because you have an infinite number of numbers. Giving you an infinity/infinity chance. Which I'm pretty sure should come out to a probability of 1, or certain.

I know Infinity is a concept, not a number so you technically can't divide. But think about it an infinite number of tries to get something. So surely irrational numbers are impossible, just we can't generate them far enough to find the end/repeat.

Thank you in advance. Also, try to remember I'm 15. I'm good with concepts of stuff and will probably understand but you may have to say what some words mean. Sorry

Comment: This is because there are different sizes of infinity countable and uncountable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for philosophy.SE?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut

Comment: The decimal representation of numbers is not the definition of numbers whether integer, rational, or irrational.  It is just a familiar and convenient but not perfect notation.  Irrational numbers have been considered long before this notation became popular.  There is more than one formal definition of the real numbers but all of the common ones are consistent.  None rely on the decimal notation.  They were intended to solve the problem that a graph of $y = x^2$ clearly has a solution yet no rational $x$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: As you are 15, you probably won't learn any of the formal definitions of the real numbers for a while.  You will probably need to go to university and study maths to meet it.  Or study yourself if you are ambitious.

Comment: you are mixing representation of quantities using numbers with quantities themselves. As you see irrational quantities cannot be represented with the standard numbers because you will need a list of infinite numbers, what cannot be written. However these quantities exists, by example the ratio between the diameter of a circle and it perimeter exists and is the irrational number $\pi$.

Comment: A mistake in my first comment but it is too late to correct it.  The formula should have been $y = x^2 - 2$.  The stated one has an obvious solution.

Comment: You're mixing existence in a mathematical sense and existence in a tangible, physical sense. Mathematical objects do not exist because we build them using finite pieces one step at a time. Mathematical objects exists because we can deduce their existence from axioms, we can prove that $\sqrt2$ is irrational and that $\pi$ is irrational, and these are nice and definable objects that we can talk about quite easily, without referring to their decimal expansion.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299065/truth-of-x2-2-0/2299096#2299096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need formal definitions: already the ancient greek mathematicians knew that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and they could prove it, so irrational numbers do exist. The chances you (or anybody) can tell us its decimal expansion (*all* digits!) are zero, indeed, that's where your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> So each time you add a new number you reduce the chances.

You make a mistake here.

Consider the irrational number given by $0.1010010001000010000010000001\dots$. Each time you add a $1$ you know with certainty that a $1$ will appear after so many $0$s.